# Render layout without a template in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I have a rails application that is using ember and in my routes I have all routes going to `application#ember`. This requires me to have an empty `application/ember.html.erb` (which is empty). It's only there to appease rails and let ember start.

How do I render the layout without an associated template?

**routes.rb**

```
match '*path' => 'application#ember', via: %i[get post]
```

**views/application/ember.html.erb**

```
# empty! I only exist to make rails happy!
```

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible or not? or are u asking how to do it?, it seems to me it should be working the way u already have it

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady using `render inline: ''` doesn't cause the layout to render. I currently have an empty template which is what I'm trying to eliminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
render html: '', layout: true
```

It's important to note that the `layout: true` part is required